# Set filename and path progmatically with PrintDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Hope this is an easy one.

I'm writing this WPF software with VS2017, I need to print the visual to an .xps file at some point and I managed to get this working like this:

```
private void cmdPrintClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {         

            PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();
            print.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), "XPS"); //XPS is the Microsoft XPS Document Writer
            print.PrintVisual(myWindow, "Window"); //myWindow is the visual I want to print

        }
```

This is working just fine.

What I am trying to achieve is to give progmatically the path and the filename, no need to show any dialog.

Thanks everyone for helping out.

Comment: You may get the details from the below link: [Send file to XPS Printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241945/send-file-to-xps-printer)

Comment: Thanks, starting from where you said I finally got it working.